# .NET method to round a number up to the nearest multiple of another number?

Tags: .net, rounding

I'm looking for a method that can round a number *up* to the nearest multiple of another.  This is similar Quantization.

Eg.  If I want to round 81 up to the nearest multiple of 20, it should return 100.

Is there a method built-in method in the .NET framework I can use for this?

The reason I'm asking for a built-in method is because there's a good chance it's been optimized already.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, integer arithmetic.

To round m up to the next multiple of n, use ((m+n-1)/n)*n

Comment: Also, the "next multiple" of a negative number is actually rounding down.

Comment: You seemed to have missed the part where I asked for a "built-in" method.

Comment: To put it a little more mnemonically: To round the number n up to the next multiple of m, use `((n+m-1)/m)*m`.

Answer (score 8):

```
public static int RoundUp(int num, int multiple)
{
  if (multiple == 0)
    return 0;
  int add = multiple / Math.Abs(multiple);
  return ((num + multiple - add) / multiple)*multiple;
}


static void Main()
{
  Console.WriteLine(RoundUp(5, -2));
  Console.WriteLine(RoundUp(5, 2));
}

/* Output
 * 4
 * 6
*/
```

Answer (score 6):

Lee's answer is good but it should have been:

```
t = m + n - 1; return (t - (t % m));
```

Notice the change from `N` to `M`. The modulo operation should be done with the multiplier `(m)` and not with the number `(n)`.

Comment: Good catch. Things got confusing as soon as people starting using 'm' for the number and 'n' for the multiple -- which seems counter-intuitive at best.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a lot of these on a relatively slow platform, you may eliminate the multiplication by using a variant of:

t = m + n - 1;
return (t - (t % n));

Of course, if you can limit your multiple to values of 2^n, then the modulus operation may also be deprecated in favour of its logical equivalent (usually "&").

Incidentally, the "RoundUp" function illustrated above is seriously flawed and will only round down correctly when {(m % n) == (n - 1)}; rounding down is implicit for integer division and as such, does not require compensation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that explains *why* that particular bit of arithmetic solves the problem, in case it's not obvious to the reader.

Let our number be *n* and our multiple be *m*.

If we were doing real arithmetic, we might divide *n* by *m*, then round up and multiply the result by *m*. With *n* = 81 and *m* = 20, *n*/*m* = 4.05. Round up to 5. 5 * 20 = 100.

But we're not doing real arithmetic, we're doing integer arithmetic. If you divide *n* by *m*, the result is truncated, and rounding up doesn't work. So, we first add *m* to *n* before dividing, to get the rounded up number after the division, then multiple by *m* to get the final result.

So, 81 + 20 = 101. 101 / 20 = 5 (truncated). 5*20 = 100.

However, if the number is already a multiple, then adding *m* will give us the wrong result. If instead of 81, *n* = 100, we would have this:

100 + 20 = 120. 120 / 20 = 6. 6 * 20 = 120.

So, to avoid that, don't add *m*. Add *m* - 1. That's guaranteed to push our dividend up over the next threshold, without causing a mistake in the edge case where *n* is already a multiple of *m*.

81 + 19 = 100. 100 / 20 = 5. 5 * 20 = 100

100 + 19 = 119. 119 / 20 = 5 (truncated). 5 * 20 = 100

That gives us the final formula already seen in other answers:

((*n* + (*m* - 1)) / *m*) * *m*