# Round an integer number in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, numbers

How could I round an integer number based on the last digit of the number?

For example:

```
Dim x As Integer = 12
Dim y As Integer = 139
Dim z As Integer = 2322
```

The result should be:

```
x = 20
y = 140
z = 2330
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Looks like you are always rounding up, 12 rounded would round down to 10 normally.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380944/net-method-to-round-a-number-up-to-the-nearest-multiple-of-another-number

Comment: Use integer math: `value = ((value + 9) \ 10) * 10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
Math.Ceiling(value / 10) * 10
```

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48.aspx#Y0

Answer (score 1):

```
x = Math.Ceiling(x / 10.0) * 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Module Module1
    Public Function RoundUp(ByVal val As Double, ByVal pos As Integer) As Double
        Dim base10 As Double = System.Math.Pow(10, pos) 'pos +: right from float point, -: left from float point. 

        If val > 0 Then
            Return System.Math.Ceiling(val * base10) / base10
        Else
            Return System.Math.Floor(val * base10) / base10
        End If
    End Function
    Sub Main()
        System.Console.WriteLine(RoundUp(12, -1)) '20
        System.Console.WriteLine(RoundUp(139, -1)) '140
        System.Console.WriteLine(RoundUp(2322, -1)) '2330
        System.Console.WriteLine(RoundUp(3.1415926, 3)) '3.142
        System.Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, doing this subtraction is a fast way:

```
x = value + ((2200000000 - value) % 10)
```

Considering that value is `int` (2200000000 > `int.MaxValue`):