# round to nearest 5000

Tags: vb.net

How would I round to the nearest 5000 in vb.net. Can't use math.round cause it gives error. I'm looking for something like mround() in microsoft exel.

```
  Math.round(43333 * 34, 5000)
```

Comment: _What error do you get_?

Comment: Decimal can only round to between 0 and 28 digits of precision.
Parameter name: decimals

Comment: The second parameter to `Round()` is the number of digits, not the number to round to.

Comment: dang im dumb, how would I round to the nearest 5000 then?

Comment: When you say round to the nearest 5000, what result are you looking for? `43333 * 34` should round to... what? `1475000`?

Comment: Just noticed the mention of Excel's MROUND. See [.NET method to round a number up to the nearest multiple of another number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380944/net-method-to-round-a-number-up-to-the-nearest-multiple-of-another-number) for equivalent behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```vb
Math.Round(43000 / 5000) * 5000
```

As in:

```vb
For Each x In New Single() {2499, 2501, 7000, 21000, 43000, 99000}
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format( _
            "Rounding {0,7:N0} to the nearest 5,000: {1,7:N0}", _
            x, _
            Math.Round(x / 5000) * 5000) _
        )
Next

Console.ReadKey(True)
```

Outputs:

```
Rounding   2,499 to the nearest 5,000:       0
Rounding   2,501 to the nearest 5,000:   5,000
Rounding   7,000 to the nearest 5,000:   5,000
Rounding  21,000 to the nearest 5,000:  20,000
Rounding  43,000 to the nearest 5,000:  45,000
Rounding  99,000 to the nearest 5,000: 100,000
```

I'll add that the default rounding behavior for [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as4h66hd.aspx) is [`MidpointRounding.ToEven`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx) which the documentation describes as "*When a number is halfway between two others, it is rounded toward the nearest even number.*" This means that `0.5` may be rounded to `0` or `1` depending on the circumstances (which is the desired behavior when dealing with statistics). To change this behavior, you can pass `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` as the second parameter, which will behave as you were taught in school (`0.5` always rounds to `1`, `-0.5` always rounds to `-1`).

Comment: Isn't the use of `Math.Round()` superfluous here? `/ 5000` will already result in integer division.

Comment: @DanJ - you are correct, but I'm assuming that the variables involved are `Float`s

Comment: You might consider specifying them as non-integer literals, then. ;) Another quirk: this always rounds down, doesn't it? 43333 is closer to 45000 than to 40000...

Comment: @DanJ - Don't think so, as long as the numeral or denominator is a floating point/decimal value.

Comment: @DanJ - Actually, after checking it in the Visual Studios, I've realized that in VB `43000 / 5000` results in a float. You must use `43000 \ 5000` to introduce integer division. The original code would work as-is. I think we were both getting confused with C#, which has the behavior you were referencing. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25bswc76.aspx